# Duplicate post has been deleted

Tags: support, specific-question, exact-duplicates

The post [Install programs from command line on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/752189/install-programs-from-command-line-on-windows) has been closed and marked as a dupe. If you click on [the dupe](https://superuser.com/questions/351928/anything-like-the-debian-package-manager-for-windows) you'll see the post has been deleted.

Not sure if you'd consider it a bug, but IMO it is because when I click on it (and whilst not logged in) I get a Page Not Found... Why show me a duplicate if it's not found (which arguably means it's not a dupe)!

Comment: IMO, the one that is still alive could do with falling down some stairs as well.

Comment: It's not a bug.   A question has to be reopened to remove the duplicate banner

Comment: @Ramhound, you can only see it due to you being logged in/your rep etc. If you try it without being logged in, then the website shows us an internal link and provides a 404 page... This is due to mechanics of the website. To me, it should not be possible (if a dupe is cited, then the parent can't be closed (and if it is closed, then the cited link should be removed (yes, this then becomes very complex)))

Comment: I know that; I noticed it also.  The duplicate question would have to be reopened.  The duplicate header is static and doesn't get updated unless we do something to the question

Answer (score 1):

That's deliberate. Links that are added in to point to canonical questions do not automatically get removed if they themselves are deleted.

If it was not closed as a duplicate it would have been closed as a product/app recommendation.

Either way it has been deleted.

Comment: I understand the question would have been deleted anyhow but that is not the question. The question is a post on the SU website provides a source of information (the link), and that the destination doesn't exist. The link is duff... People are downvoted here for link only answers because links go bad! Well, *that* link has gone bad :)

Comment: @Dave And it's been taken of. Thanks for reporting it. Next time just raise a mod flag on the question. It's overkill to report it on meta :)